# How to initialize secondary/other datasources programatically without reading application.properties

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, multi-tenant

I have a developed a multi-tenancy spring boot application where in the datasources are initialized via database credentials stored in application.properties as shown below :

application.properties

```
spring.multitenancy.datasource1.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db1
spring.multitenancy.datasource1.username=root
spring.multitenancy.datasource1.password=****
spring.multitenancy.datasource1.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update

spring.multitenancy.datasource2.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db2
spring.multitenancy.datasource2.username=root
spring.multitenancy.datasource2.password=****
spring.multitenancy.datasource2.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update

spring.multitenancy.datasource3.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db3
spring.multitenancy.datasource3.username=root
spring.multitenancy.datasource3.password=****
spring.multitenancy.datasource3.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
```

DataSourceConfig.java

```
@Configuration
public class DataSourceConfig {

    @Autowired
    private MultitenancyProperties multitenancyProperties;

    @Bean(name = { "dataSource", "dataSource1" })
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.multitenancy.datasource1")
    public DataSource dataSource1() {
        DataSourceBuilder factory = DataSourceBuilder
                .create(this.multitenancyProperties.getDatasource1().getClassLoader())
                .driverClassName(this.multitenancyProperties.getDatasource1().getDriverClassName())
                .username(this.multitenancyProperties.getDatasource1().getUsername())
                .password(this.multitenancyProperties.getDatasource1().getPassword())
                .url(this.multitenancyProperties.getDatasource1().getUrl());
        return factory.build();
    }

    @Bean(name = "dataSource2")
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.multitenancy.datasource2")
    public DataSource dataSource2() {
        DataSourceBuilder factory = DataSourceBuilder
                .create(this.multitenancyProperties.getDatasource2().getClassLoader())
                .driverClassName(this.multitenancyProperties.getDatasource2().getDriverClassName())
                .username(this.multitenancyProperties.getDatasource2().getUsername())
                .password(this.multitenancyProperties.getDatasource2().getPassword())
                .url(this.multitenancyProperties.getDatasource2().getUrl());
        return factory.build();
    }

    @Bean(name = "dataSource3")
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.multitenancy.datasource3")
    public DataSource dataSource3() {
        DataSourceBuilder factory = DataSourceBuilder
                .create(this.multitenancyProperties.getDatasource3().getClassLoader())
                .driverClassName(this.multitenancyProperties.getDatasource3().getDriverClassName())
                .username(this.multitenancyProperties.getDatasource3().getUsername())
                .password(this.multitenancyProperties.getDatasource3().getPassword())
                .url(this.multitenancyProperties.getDatasource3().getUrl());
        return factory.build();
    }
}
```

Here, data sources are initialized via values stored in application properties.

MultitenancyProperties.java

```
@ConfigurationProperties("spring.multitenancy")
public class MultitenancyProperties {

    @NestedConfigurationProperty
    private DataSourceProperties datasource1;

    @NestedConfigurationProperty
    private DataSourceProperties datasource2;

    @NestedConfigurationProperty
    private DataSourceProperties datasource3;

    public DataSourceProperties getDatasource1() {
        return datasource1;
    }

    public void setDatasource1(DataSourceProperties datasource1) {
        this.datasource1 = datasource1;
    }

    public DataSourceProperties getDatasource2() {
        return datasource2;
    }

    public void setDatasource2(DataSourceProperties datasource2) {
        this.datasource2 = datasource2;
    }

    public DataSourceProperties getDatasource3() {
        return datasource3;
    }

    public void setDatasource3(DataSourceProperties datasource3) {
        this.datasource3 = datasource3;
    }
}
```

Spring boot application launcher

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class)
@EnableConfigurationProperties(MultitenancyProperties.class)
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext ctx = SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

How to initialize only primary datasource by reading the application.properties and other datasources(dataSource2,dataSource3) programatically by reading the database credentials stored in a table of primary datasource.

Comment: By just doing it that way? Create a table that holds the data, create a `BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor` and implement the `postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry` and add `BeanDefinitions` based on the content from the database.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Can you please provide me an example/code snippet which will be very helpful.

Comment: https://blog.jdriven.com/2015/04/spicy-spring-dynamically-create-your-own-beandefinition/

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have a DB in your primay datasource of the name `DATABASECONFIG` and the following schema:

```
+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
|                         DATABASECONFIG                    |
+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| DB_NAME   |     URL   |  USERNAME | PASSWORD  |  DRIVER   |
+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
```

You can change `DataSourceConfig` class to something like:

```
@Configuration
public class DataSourceConfig {

    @Autowired
    private MultitenancyProperties multitenancyProperties;

    @Bean(name = { "dataSource", "dataSource1" })
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.multitenancy.datasource1")
    public DataSource dataSource1() throws SQLException {
        ClassLoader classLoader = this.multitenancyProperties.getDatasource1().getClassLoader();
        DataSourceBuilder factory = DataSourceBuilder
                .create(this.multitenancyProperties.getDatasource1().getClassLoader())
                .driverClassName(this.multitenancyProperties.getDatasource1().getDriverClassName())
                .username(this.multitenancyProperties.getDatasource1().getUsername())
                .password(this.multitenancyProperties.getDatasource1().getPassword())
                .url(this.multitenancyProperties.getDatasource1().getUrl());
        return factory.build();
    }

    @Bean(name = "dataSource2")
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.multitenancy.datasource2")
    public DataSource dataSource2()
            throws Exception {
        String dataSourceName = "datasource2";
        return this.getSecondaryDataSource(dataSourceName);
    }

    @Bean(name = "dataSource3")
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.multitenancy.datasource3")
    public DataSource dataSource3()
            throws Exception {
        String dataSourceName = "datasource3";
        return this.getSecondaryDataSource(dataSourceName);
    }

    private DataSource getSecondaryDataSource(String dataSourceName)
            throws Exception {
        DataSource d = this.dataSource1();
        PreparedStatement preparedStatement = d.getConnection().prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM DATABASECONFIG WHERE DB_NAME = ?");
        preparedStatement.setString(1, dataSourceName);
        ResultSet resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
        if (!resultSet.next()) {
            // No result found --> throw exception
            throw new Exception("Error Finding DB Config for DataSource [" + dataSourceName + "].");
        }
        DataSourceBuilder factory = DataSourceBuilder
                .create()
                .driverClassName(resultSet.getString("DRIVER"))
                .username(resultSet.getString("USERNAME"))
                .password(resultSet.getString("PASSWORD"))
                .url(resultSet.getString("URL"));
        return factory.build();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do the following:

Properties file

```
spring.multitenancy.datasource1.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db1
spring.multitenancy.datasource1.username=root
spring.multitenancy.datasource1.password=****
spring.multitenancy.datasource1.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
```

Spring Configuration

```
@Configuration
public class DataSourceConfig {

    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.multitenancy.datasource1")
    private DataSourceProperties ds;

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource1() {
        DataSourceBuilder factory = DataSourceBuilder
                .create(ds.getClassLoader())
                .driverClassName(ds.getDriverClassName())
                .username(ds.getUsername())
                .password(ds.getPassword())
                .url(ds.getUrl());
        return factory.build();
    }
    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource2() {
        createFromDataSource1Conf("key2");
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource3() {
        createFromDataSource1Conf("key3");
    }

    private DataSource createFromDataSource1Conf(Object configPrefix) {
        // Query db and create datasources
    }

}
```

I am not quite sure that using @ConfigurationProperties this way will work, but you can always use it like you do now.

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.multitenancy.datasource1")
private DataSourceProperties ds;
```

Answer (score 0):

Split your @Configuration class in two. Create the primary datasource in the first then [autowire it into the second](http://docs.spring.io/spring-javaconfig/docs/1.0.0.M4/reference/html/ch04s02.html); making it available to slave datasource @Bean methods.

Answer (score -1):

First you could import commons-dbcp2.jar,then you could create a org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource,eg,

```
 BasicDataSource ds = new BasicDataSource();
    ds.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    ds.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/housesearch");
    ds.setUsername("root");
    ds.setPassword("");
    ds.setInitialSize(50);
    ds.setMaxIdle(30);
    Connection connection = ds.getConnection();
    Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
    ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery("select * from pay_info");
    if(resultSet.next()){
        System.out.println(resultSet.getInt(5));
    }
    connection.close();
    ds.close();
```

The driverClassName, url, password and other properties can be stored in a table.

I wish my answer could help you.